# C# generic interface. The type T must be convertable to T2 in order to use it as parameter in the generic interface

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
public interface IRequest<out TResponse>
{
}

public interface IPagedRequest<out TResponse> : IRequest<IPagedList<TResponse>>
{
    int Page { get; set; }
    int PageSize { get; set; }
}

public interface IRequestHandler<in TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    Task<TResponse> HandleAsync(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}

public interface IPagedList<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    //...
}
```

I need to create decorator for IRequestHandler to process all IPagedRequest's. So I wrote that:

```
public class PagedRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : class, IPagedRequest<TResponse>
{
    // ...
}
```

and these code doesn't work, because: "The type TRequest must be convertable to IRequest in order to use it as parameter TRequest in generic interface IRequestHandler".

The question is: how to solve this problem and why it happens?

Comment: It happens because of your `where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>` on the `IRequestHandler<in TRequest, TResponse>` interface

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Is correct.  When extrapolated out, you are making the promise that `TRequest` is both `IRequest<TResponse>` _and_ `IRequest<IEnumerable<TResponse>>`.  Since `TResponse` cannot also be `IEnumerable<TResponse>`, the contract fails.